# Small image is overlapping my navigation?

Tags: html, css

With character: http://jsfiddle.net/nuu6g/

For some reason, I cannot click on my text on my navigation menu. This is most likely due to the (missing) image on the left, which I will refer to as the "character." However, when I remove the character, I can indeed click on the text again.

Without character: http://jsfiddle.net/aN5s5/

```
body {
    background:grey;
}

.topContainer {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 125px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#logo {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
/* Navigation */
 #navigation {
    background: #107AEB;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#107AEB), to(#106FEB));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #107AEB, #106FEB);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #107AEB, #106FEB);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #107AEB, #106FEB);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #107AEB, #106FEB);
    border: 2px solid rgba(16, 86, 235, 0.9);
    border-radius: 15px;
    float: right;
    width: 455px;
    height: 55px;
    margin-top: 22px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#navigation ul {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#navigation li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#navigation a {
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: SEGOEUIL, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 17px;
}
#navigation a:hover {
    background: rgba(16, 86, 235, 0.9);
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#navigation a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navigation a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.character {
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0 275px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    width: 187px;
    height: 174px;
}
/* Wrapper */
 #wrapper {
    background: #FFF;
    /*rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);*/
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1200px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#photoContent {
    background: #ffcc00;
    border: 1px solid #b62100;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 781px;
    height: 231px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.displayPhoto {
    width: 771px;
    height: 221px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #b62100;
}
#leftContent {
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 140px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 45px;
}
.title {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #3abfee;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.desc {
    color: #575757;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
#rightContent {
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 140px;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 25px;
}
#flashContent {
    padding-left: 25px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 500px;
}
hr {
    width: 750px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #CCC;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
/* Bottom Wrapper */
 #bwCont {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.galleryCont {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 650px;
    height: 150px;
}
.galleryImgCont {
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    float: left;
}
.galleryTitle {
    font-family:'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    padding-top: 145px;
}
.galleryDesc {
    font-family:'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

#galleryImg {
    width: 175px;
    height: 125px;
    border: 5px solid #F5F5F5;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
}
.readMore {
    width: 175px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #000;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family:'SEGOEUIL', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.readMore:hover {
    background: #202020;
}
```

Please help me, thanks! Also, just an extra question; is there any way I can keep the read more buttons inline, instead of like a staircase? Sorry, but thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your links to be "clickable", either adjust the padding/width of `#character` or use the following CSS so `#navigation` comes up top of `#character`

```
#navigation {
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/854jt/)

---

For "Read More" to be aligned, you're going to need to have the same number of lines in the title and the description, or you can set a minimum height (or even just the height) of those by adding the following CSS for eaxmple:

```
.galleryTitle {
   min-height:40px;
}

.galleryDesc {
   min-height:60px;
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/A5bjz/)

Answer (score 0):

Your nav items are displaying in a staircase because there is not enough room due to the width of your ul.  adding width 100% will allow them to display inline the way you want.

```
#navigation ul {
    width: 100%
}
```

the reason you can't click your text link is because of your character class overlaying your images with a higher z-index.

Comment: I meant the black buttons on the bottom that state "Read More." Thank you though.